# fingerprint-gui can not recognize my upek reader (147e:1002)

Tags: fingerprint-reader

I've got a new laptop which is Lenove's E420s.
And I have encountered a big problem that I can't make the fingerprint reader work properly.

I've also tried fingerprint-gui. But unfortunately, it's told that "No Device Found".
Here is my screenshot:
http://ge.tt/98Xg2WD/v/0

It's said that 147e:1002 is supported by fingerprint-gui on the official website.

So, I'm curious about the situation.
Anybody knows?

P.S: I'm using gentoo, but I think this problem may not have anything to do with distribution since I compiled the source from official site.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same device in my System 76 Serval. fprint_demo, fingerprint-gui, fingerprint-identifier will only recognise my fingerprint reader when I run them with gksudo.

I suspect it needs a udev rule created for it in order to run properly.

Comment: good explanation! But it does not work here using gksudo..T_T

Comment: In my case it was actually because my user account wasn't in either of the following user groups : scanner, usbdev.

Answer (score 2):

I have the exact same fingerprint reader (147e:1002 Upek unknown device) and have the problem as you've described - that it does not recognise the device.

Despite this, I've found that fingerprint GUI still works - that you can scan in your fingerprint and use it as the program intended, although it is currently not officially supported by fprint. You have to install **libbsapi** driver.

Comment: How can I scan in my fingerprint in the case that those functional tabs are gray?

Comment: Do you have the same fingerprint reader?

Comment: my id is 147e:1002, is that the same as yours?